# Como fazer a contagem de visualizações das página em um site

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, mongodb

Gostaria de implementar um contador de visualizações de página em meu site, apresentar uma referência númerica no site, e usar esses dados para realizar um ranking de artigos/post mais acessados e inserir automaticamente a um widget, na barra lateral do site.

Node.js resolve o problema, ele faz essa ponte entre front e back usando javascript, onde estou mais familiarizado, posso acessar o banco de dados, seja MongoBD e/ou MySQL e aprender uma linguagem que dominará em um futuro breve. Agora é dedicar ao aprendizagem, vamos em frente!

Comment: Para que fim você precisa desta informação? Apenas para análise? Caso sim, utilize o Google Analytics (http://analytics.google.com). Depois basta implementar em seu site o código de rastreamento e conseguirá suas informações, inclusive verificar os visitantes em tempo real.

Comment: Para análise você pode usar o [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com.br/analytics/), agora para criar um sistema própio de rankin de conteúdo mais acessado, você precisa calcular todas as visitas registrar em um banco de dados e depois exibir essas informações. Pode ser feito basicamente com qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Não são apenas uma tag, não Ricardo, quero mais que apenas analisar.

Comment: Você pode criar uma tabela em seu banco de dados e a cada vez que a página for requisitada use um for() para adicionar +1 ao registro do banco! caso queira fazer um contador único use cookies para salvar o usuário e não registrar novamente no banco de dados caso ele tenha visitado a página! Agora isso varia se você for fazer em procedural ou orientada a objetos!
Essa foi a primeira lógica que me veio a cabeça, mas tem muitos meios de fazer isso!

Comment: Se o oque você precisa não pode ser suprido pelo uso do analytics, então o melhor seria usar um banco de dados para isso e inserir um php(ou a linguagem server-side que você preferir) para acrescentar +1 no numero de visitas daquela página no banco de dados... Depois para puxar isso num widget seria só pegar os dados do banco... Se faltar alguma coisa comenta aqui que vou completando a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Deve ser criado uma tabela(se for o caso de um banco relacional) com 2 campos basicos, ID do post e a quantidade de visualizações, ficarria mais ou menos assim a tabela

```
| id | id_post | qnt |
----------------------
| 30 | 000050  | 010 |
----------------------
| 31 | 000014  | 017 |
----------------------
```

Depois criaria um script/ou função que todas as vezes que a página de visualização de blog fosse chamado, então com o `id` em mãos (e você deve ter) do post, você passaria para essa função. Assim seria incrementado 1 ao registro referente ao post.

Comment: E quanto à linguagem a ser utilizada, o ideal é que seja na linguagem que está sendo desenvolvido o sistema.

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo a parte de ação usando Jquery. ainda estou tentando raciocinar como ficaria a tabela no banco de dados.

Comment: JQuery será carregado no browser, e depois executado. Ele não será executado no servidor. Então se for utilizar JQuery vc deve requisitar via ajax uma url que gravará os dados que foi citado acima.

Comment: Node.js resolve o problema, ele faz essa ponte entre front e back usando javascript, onde estou mais familiarizado, posso acessar o banco de dados, seja MongoBD e/ou MySQL e aprender uma linguagem que dominará em um futuro breve. Agora é dedicar ao aprendizagem, vamos em frente!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie uma página chamanda contador.php, ela deve estar vazia se nenhum código nela.

Depois crie outro arquivo index.php

```
<?php
$a = 0;
include 'contador.php';
if (isset($_COOKIE['counte'])) {
  $counte = $_COOKIE['counte'] + 1;
}else{
$counte = 1;
$a++; 
}
setcookie('counte', "$counte", time()+3700);
$abre =@fopen("contador.php","w");
 $ss ='<?php $a='.$a.'; ?>';
 $escreve =fwrite($abre, $ss);
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>Contador de Visitas</head>
 <body>

<?php 
echo "<br>$a Pessoas visitaram esse site e você já visitou" .$counte. "vezes";
?>  

 <p>Conteúdo do seu site</p>

<?php $a=0; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara não é de visitas... Quero de visualização dos artigos em meu site e depois ranquear, como disse o @Ricardo, os mais acessados.

Comment: Acredito que essa não é a melhor opção, e também não cumpre o papel na hora de realizar o ranking dos mais acessados.

Comment: Esse vídeo mostra algumas coisas talvez úteis para você.

vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5px-GRRFC08

Comment: Vou assistir, vlw. Espero outras soluções dos mestres no assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Solução parra laravel

Jquery--->>

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var getVisits  = sessionStorage.getItem('visit_'+"{{ $page_tag }}");
        if(!getVisits)
        {
            var saveVisits = sessionStorage.setItem('visit_'+"{{ $page_tag }}", 1);
            $.ajax("{{ route("visits") }}/" + "{{ $page_tag }}/" + saveVisits);
        }
    });
</script>
```

--> Php Route

```
Route::get('visits/{page_tag?}/{visit_count?}', function ($page_tag){
    $page = \App\Models\Pages::where('tag', $page_tag)->get()->first();
    $page->visits = $page->visits + 1;
    $page->save();
})->name('visits');
```